# How do you mock the Auth::id in Laravel 6 testing?

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I'm trying to test a `post` route in a my laravel project.

In my controller one of the fields grabs the `Auth::id` to insert into the database:

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
  public function create(ValidateOrder $request, FileStorageServiceInterface $disk)
  {   
    return Order::create([
      'user_id' => Auth::id(),
      *rest of inserts*
    ]);
  }
}
```

This is the test function currently:

```
public function testCreateOrder()
{
    $user = new User([
        'id' => 1,
        *rest of user info*
    ]);

    $this->be($user);
    
    $data = [
        *order data*
    ];

    $response = $this->post('/order', $data);

    $response->assertStatus(201);
}
```

Once I test I receive:

```
Expected status code 201 but received 500.
```

When I `dd$($response)` in the `testCreateOrder()`, in the `errorInfo` I'm getting:

```
"Column 'user_id' cannot be null"
```

I've been trying for the past few hours to figure out how to mock the `Auth::id` somehow by using `$this->be($user)` and `$this->actingAs($user)` and a handful of other solutions in hopes it carry's to the controller are can be used there.

It's my first time testing in Laravel and I'm a little stumped with this one so any help would be greatly appreciated :).

Also, the function works in actuality, it's just the testing side that's causing me a few problems.

Comment: You are not authenticate, login and try again. Its better to do a `Auth::check()` before call the `Auth::id()`

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm trying to mock a log in through my test function so that when the test post request is sent it can use the user I've mocked to grab the id from `Auth::id()`.

Comment: @sta Read the question again please. The code works for normal user interaction, but is failing for unit/feature tests; the code `$this->be($user)` is for authentication (supposedly), so by all accounts, they **are** authenticated, and they can't "login and try again"...

Comment: @TimLewis yeah it's definitely that, `dd(Auth::id())` is bringing back `.....null` and `dd(Auth::user())` is bringing back the user but without the id. Interesting.

Comment: Ah, probably because `new User()` doesn't actually save them, and until they are saved, they don't have a primary key (`id` in this case). If you did `$user->save();` before `$this->be($user);`, it _should_ work, but I haven't worked in this kind of testing environment before 

Comment: You were absolutely right @TimLewis, all I had to do was that and add the password field in. Thanks!

Comment: You should look at factories for creating test data. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#writing-factories

Comment: @miken32 thanks, I'm going to do that. I've just been using a class function for creating a user so far. It's worked pretty nicely but I've read it's better to use factories so I will in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to save the user before setting the user for the test.

$user->save();

$this->be($user);

Thanks @TimLewis!

Answer (score 0):

i would try couple of things:

1. in the create controller func, dump out Auth::id() or Auth::user() to see if it is 'set' during test
2. change your test to follow this:

````
    $data = [
        *order data*
    ];

    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->post('/order', $data)
        ->assertCreated(); 
    ```
````